# Polynomial root finders with consistent root ordering

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

When it comes to solving simple polynomials with complex coefficients and complex roots, we can use explicit formulae.  For example, the roots for polynomial $z^2-c$ are the list $(\sqrt c,-\sqrt c)$.  A small perturbation in the coefficients will result in a small perturbation of the roots, but the list will not be permuted.

For polynomials of higher degree we will use some kind of numerical procedure that gives us a list of roots.  But running the numerical procedure on the same polynomial a second time may give us the same roots in a different order (because it may have used randomness in selecting the starting point of an iteration).  And even if that's not the case, there is no guarantee that perturbing the polynomial slightly will yield the perturbed roots in the same order as the roots of the original.

For example, a numerical solver might give the roots of $z^2-c$ as $(\operatorname N(\sqrt c),-\operatorname N(\sqrt c))$ and the roots of $z^2-(c+\epsilon)$ as $(-\operatorname N(\sqrt {c+\epsilon},\operatorname N(\sqrt {c+\epsilon}))$, where $\operatorname N()$ is a numerical approximation.

Are there numerical root finders that preserve root order as well as formula based solvers?  (There are some complexities that are discussed in the comments ... it impossible for roots to vary continuously with coefficients everywhere - even formula based solvers will have branch cuts)

The polynomials I'm interested in are of small degree - less than 10.  And I would be happiest if the answer also pointed to a reliable open source implementation.

Comment: You are assuming that the roots are real and will stay real under small perturbation.  You should read about [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial), though it is of degree $20$..  All its roots are real and well separated, but perturbing one coefficient by a relative error of $2^{-29}$ sends the roots off into the complex plane, four with imaginary parts greater than $2$.

Comment: The perturbation-invariant part of this is impossible for topological reasons. Consider the polynomial family $z^2-e^{it}$. If the algorithm produces the result $(1,-1)$ when $t=0$ and is invariant under small perturbations of $t$, it must produce the result $(e^{it/2},-e^{it/2})$. But that means that when you get to $t=2\pi$ you get the same roots in the opposite order, for the same polynomial.

Comment: @Ross, I'm not assuming the roots are real.  If some part of the question implies that, let me know and I will try to fix it.

Comment: If the roots aren't real the concept of order becomes more difficult because the complex numbers do not have an obvious order.  In the Wilkinson example it is not easy to say which root in the original polynomial corresponds to which root in the perturbed polynomial, so it is not clear what order you want the roots of the perturbed polynomial produced in.

Comment: @Micah, good point.  I'll admit I'm struggling to formulate the right question, and maybe the perturbation idea is the wrong way to go.  I've got a vague idea that if the polynomial is an $n$-fold covering with $n$ sheets that the roots should be in 'sheet order' if that makes any sense.  So it's ok for there to be the kind of discontinuity that your example would imply - at cuts between the sheets.

Comment: @Micah, even with a formula like $\sqrt c$ the roots will occasionally jump.  But I'd like a numeric solver that behaves as much as possible like a formula based solver.  In other words, most of the time the roots move continuously with the coefficients, with jump cuts here and there.

Comment: @Ross, I'd have to look closer at your example but I'd imagine that if you make the perturbations small enough you'd see how the roots correspond.  I might have to refine my question though to address the issues brought up in these comments.

Comment: I might need something like https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201280.pdf, but I haven't read the paper yet.  Was looking for some guidance in a field I know next to nothing about.

Comment: It is true that if the perturbations are small enough the roots are continuous functions of the coefficients.  What happens is that two roots move toward each other, meet on the real line, then *zip* off in the imaginary direction.  The perturbation required for this is *tiny*.  I suspect it is because polynomials don't like having equally spaced roots.

Comment: You are free to sort the roots (say, by real component first, then by imaginary) after you find them. It will almost certainly be much cheaper computationally to sort the roots than it would be to use a less efficient algorithm.

Comment: Your question reminds me of work a former colleague of mine (S. Kranich) had been doing. [*An epsilon-delta bound for plane algebraic curves and its use for certified homotopy continuation of systems of plane algebraic curves*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03432) is the best reference I can find for that at the moment. It would relate separation of roots to permitted perturbation, I believe. Perhaps the “[homotopy continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_continuation)” mentioned in that title is the kind of concept you meant to ask for?

Comment: @MvG: yes, that sounds right.  Unfortunately I can't remember the original motivation for this question, but at least now I will know the proper search term. If you care to turn your comment into an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, merely a comment turned into an answer to provide potentially useful keywords and references.

Your question reminds me of work a former colleague of mine (S. Kranich) had been doing. [*An epsilon-delta bound for plane algebraic curves and its use for certified homotopy continuation of systems of plane algebraic curves*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03432) is the best reference I can find for that at the moment. It would relate separation of roots to permitted perturbation, I believe. As some comments pointed out, there are definitely some evil polynomials where that relationship is really poor, and even a tiny change in coefficients would lead to a massive change in roots, defeating the approach.

Perhaps the “[homotopy continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_continuation)” mentioned in that title is the kind of concept you meant to ask for? As I understand it, the idea is that you aim to track roots along a path from the original situation to a somewhat perturbed one. The above paper will tell you how big you may make the individual steps along this path if you want to be certain that matching roots by minimal distance will map things “correctly”, or more specifically map them the way a continuous movement with infinitely small steps would map them. Of course the path has to avoid singular situations / multiple roots if it is to have any chance at success.

I'm not sure if the above paper takes numeric issues into account. If you have a theoretic guarantee about roots having a certain guaranteed separation, then the fact that any numeric approach will only find approximations of the actual roots might water down the benefit. You might even reach a situation where the either the guaranteed situation is smaller than the expected numerical rounding error, or the step size along the path smaller than the unit in the last place of your perturbation variable.